# Postman API Keys as custom headers - Usage not being reflected in Postman account

Tags: postman, postman-newman

I made API Keys in Postman and added them as a custom header in my Postman requests. I have sent a few requests over and am still not seeing usage reflected on my Postman account? I am going to send a big request over in the following days and I want to make sure that my calls are reflected. I am using Newman to run my collection.

In Postman

1. In Postman account, my API Key has a name and a value
2. In Postman app, my key:value is in my Globals and it is also added as a custom header

In Newman

1. I am running the collection with the `newman run collection.json -g globals.json` to capture the api key:value

I have sent a few GET requests but still not seeing usage reflected. Is there latency on Postman side?

[image]

[image]